# Create CSV file from PHP query, then turn into GEOJSON file

Tags: php, csv, geojson

I have a PHP method which returns a json string as follows:

```
function getjson(){
$mun = $this->input->POST('municipality');
$sl  = $this->input->POST('saleslimit'); 
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT RollNum , Address, v2_lat, v2_lng  
    FROM tblontario WHERE Municipality = '".$mun."'"." LIMIT ".$sl);            
        $json_string = json_encode($q->result(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents('/home/apts/Dropbox/ptax.ca/js/salecomps.json', $json_string);
        echo $json_string;
}
```

Rather than return a json string, I would like to be able to return a CSV file so that I can then take that CSV file and somehow turn it into a `geojson` file that can be loaded into a [google map](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ca/2014/03/maps-made-easier-geojson-in-the-javascript-maps-api.html).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Ultimately my goal is to create a `geojson` file, but I am uncertain of the best way to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $row is an array you can just do something like:

```
function getCSV() {
    $mun = $this->input->POST('municipality');
    $sl  = $this->input->POST('saleslimit'); 
    $q = $this->db->query("
        SELECT 
            RollNum, 
            Address,
            v2_lat,
            v2_lng 
        FROM
            tblontario 
        WHERE 
            Municipality = '".$mun."'"." 
        LIMIT ".$sl
    );
    $row = $q->result();
    $csvRow = implode(",",$row);
    file_put_contents('/home/apts/Dropbox/ptax.ca/js/salecomps.csv', $csvRow);
    echo $csvRow;
}
```

Since I see a limit there, I'm guessing you're getting more than one result and that $q->result(); returns an array of results instead of just a row, in which case..

```
function getCSV() {
    $mun = $this->input->POST('municipality');
    $sl  = $this->input->POST('saleslimit'); 
    $q = $this->db->query("
        SELECT 
            RollNum, 
            Address,
            v2_lat,
            v2_lng 
        FROM
            tblontario 
        WHERE 
            Municipality = '".$mun."'"." 
        LIMIT ".$sl
    );
    $res = $q->result();
    if(!empty($res)){
        $fh = fopen('/home/apts/Dropbox/ptax.ca/js/salecomps.csv','w');
        foreach($res as $row){
            // as suggested by @GigaWatt, swapped fwrite for fputcsv
            fputcsv($fh,$row);
        }
        fclose($fh);
        echo file_get_contents('/home/apts/Dropbox/ptax.ca/js/salecomps.csv');
    } else {
        echo "";
    }

}
```

EDIT: Looking a GeoJSON spec, what you prob want is something like:

```
function getGeoJSON() {
    $mun = $this->input->POST('municipality');
    $sl  = $this->input->POST('saleslimit'); 
    $q = $this->db->query("
        SELECT 
            RollNum, 
            Address,
            v2_lat,
            v2_lng 
        FROM
            tblontario 
        WHERE 
            Municipality = '".$mun."'"." 
        LIMIT ".$sl
    );
    $res = $q->result();
    if(!empty($res)){
        $geoArr = Array(
            "type" => "MultiPoint",
            "coordinates" => Array()
        );
        foreach($res as $row) {
            $geoArr["coordinates"][] = Array($row['v2_lat'],$row['v2_lng']);
        }
        $geoJSON = json_encode($geoArr);
        file_put_contents('/home/apts/Dropbox/ptax.ca/js/salecomps.geojson',$geoJSON);
        echo $geoJSON;
    } else {
        echo "{}";
    }

}
```

Comment: `fputcsv` is probably better than reinventing CSV.

Comment: Thanks Meridion, I think that your last bit of code with the GeoJSON is what I am looking for.  Unfortunately, I am getting an error, Internal Server Error.  Not sure about how to debug this.  I'm trying . . .

Comment: Have you set error reporting to all? (error_reporting(E_ALL);)

Comment: this is the line that is causing the error:  $geoArr["coordinates"][] = Array($row['v2_lat'],$row['v2_lng']);

Comment: Weird that you say so, check it out [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b1fef94cf87bdf4d1f4f9d1bd3640d4e0647dd4), it works just fine..

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are basically looking for a getCSV() function. You can do this by manually concatenating the elements of the result set. Something like this.

```
function getCSV(){
    $mun = $this->input->POST('municipality');
    $sl  = $this->input->POST('saleslimit'); 
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT RollNum , Address, v2_lat, v2_lng FROM tblontario WHERE Municipality = '".$mun."'"." LIMIT ".$sl);
    $row = $q->result();
    $csvString =  $row->{'RollNum'}.','.$row->{'Address'}.','.$row->{'v2 lat'}.','.$row->{'v2 lng'};
    file_put_contents('/home/apts/Dropbox/ptax.ca/js/salecomps.csv', $csvString);
    echo $csvString;
}
```